# Writing Poseidon / Pedersen Hash based Time Locks on NEAR Protocol

Tags: time, cryptography, locking, blockchain, nearprotocol

I have worked on different types of time locks in Ethereum, Polkadot, Aeternity, Algorand, Cosmos etc. I could not find a time lock contract or time lock bridge on NEAR protocol yet. Can anyone suggest the best way to implement time locks on NEAR protocol.

Answer (score 1):

This should help https://docs.near.org/docs/tokens/lockup#the-lockup-contract-at-near. Here is the example from the docs:

```
{
  "owner_account_id": "gio3gio.near",        // the Owner account who is allowed to call methods on this one
  "lockup_duration": "0",                    // not necessary if the lockup_timestamp is used
  "lockup_timestamp": "1601769600000000000", // Unix timestamp for October 4th, 2020 at midnight UTC
  "transfers_information": {
    "TransfersDisabled": {
      "transfer_poll_account_id": "transfer-vote.near"
    }
  },
  "vesting_schedule": null,
  "release_duration": "31536000000000000",  // 365 days
  "staking_pool_whitelist_account_id": "lockup-whitelist.near",
  "foundation_account_id": null
}
```